# How to get a specific attribute from a CFString

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-foundation, cfstring

I want to know whether a string is single-byte encoding. The `CFShowStr` can do this work, but it output the message to the console. The `CFShowStr` function output message is look like this, the `IsEightBit` item is what I want:

```
Length 7    
IsEightBit 1    
HasLengthByte 0    
HasNullByte 1    
InlineContents 0    
Allocator SystemDefault    
Mutable 0    
Contents 0x104f9fef3
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think the eight-bit flag means what you think it does. See the documentation for `CFShowStr`:

> Use this function to learn about specific attributes of a CFString
>   object during debugging. These attributes include the following: (…)
>   Whether originally it was an 8-bit string and, if so, whether it was a
>   C (`HasNullByte`) or Pascal (`HasLengthByte`) string.

I don’t know what encoding is used internally by CFString. Why do you care about the eight-bitness? Because in most cases you should not.

Comment: the following code section use deprecate Carbon API, I want to rewrite it with non-Carbon functions.    

`if ((GetScriptVariable(smSystemScript, smScriptFlags) & smsfSingByte) == 0){}`
    
by some reason, multi-byte encoding are still used in the system

Comment: What’s the code context, what’s inside those `{}`? You might be able to rewrite the code without peeking at the implementation details at all.